# Deleting outlines when merging two maps using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.3, editing

[image]

I downloaded two digital maps / datasets. When I downloaded the two maps, the data have  outlines. After merging two datasets, it has still outline as per the attached image.

I heard If I want to delete the outlines, I have to enter the (`Open the Attribute Table -> Select by Attribute`) section(?) and the delete geographic feature codes about outlines. I don't know concrete processes.
I have geographic feature codes for topographic map in Korea if that helps.

I am using ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: is there any attributes, like 0=grid 1=contour? if so select by attributes and delete the 0=grid.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your words..I'm beginner :(

Comment: Select by Attribute -> Method(Remove from current selection)

Comment: Layer = Get Unique Values(Codes) -> Apply

Comment: is it right????

Comment: If it is right, I would like to know what codes should I select...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how your features are set up. The easiest way would be to Right-Click your contour dataset and select "Edit Features" (it is the 11th option down in the right-click menu).

Then select the outline line and press "Delete" on the keyboard.

Another method, assuming the contour dataset only contains elevation information for the contours (and the elevation in the dataset extent is all above sea-level), you could select those lines from the attribute table with an elevation of 0. You can do this by right clicking the feature in the Table of contents, opening the attribute table and choosing the "Select by Attributes" button.
Assuming the contour information is in the [Elevation] field you can add the following into the "Select by Attributes" dialog:

```
"Elevation"=0
```

Then check the map view ensuring only the outline is selected and delete these features.